# NumberFormatException convert string to int having underscore,hyphen in jdk1.7

Tags: java

In jdk1.7 we can use underscore in int,
int anInt = 0b10101000_01010001_01101000_01010001;

however if we have a string having underscore,hyphen it gives number format exception when converting to int.

why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember backward compatibility?

- All code that works (or doesn't work) in earlier versions of java should behave in same way even   if java version is changed,

So if to inculcate this feature changes
   would be made in JDK 7 then all code written in earlier
   versions of java would also not throw this exception when '_' was
   found in string. Which will be a very grave problem.

Comment: ok in simple terms why it gives the error in converting string with "-" or "_"?

Comment: simply because the characters '-' and "_" are not considered to be numbers and compiler thinks that user has given invalid input of String and wants to convert that to number

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can use "_" in literals is just "syntactic sugar" - it is a feature of the Java language that was added for pure convenience.

The designers of the Java language decided that this "convenience" only applies to Java source code (processed by a Java compiler); therefore only the compiler was updated to allow such patterns; but the "parsing" code that throws the Exceptions was not changed.

Most likely, the underlying reasoning was: it is something different to write applications that parse numbers out of text (compared to allow the compiler to understand "more readable" literals).

Answer (score 0):

Using _ in integer is used when you have group of digits (probably making sense) as part of same int variable, as in case of phone number ( 91_766986752) which is (code_number). but the integer that is returned is 91766986752 only.

ex - int anInt = 0b10101000_01010001_01101000_01010001;

In this, you can think of each parts as some sensible group of digits for ease of user or developer to understand that int consists of what. Compiler ignores these _ and gives back remaining int value

In case of String converted to Integer, _ is not ignored, thus giving 
NumberFormatException, as it is not a digit.

Ex - String "91_766986752" when converted to int will still consider _ instead of ignoring it.